# IIS web farm framework Load balancing vs classic load balancing

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7, web-farm-framework

i'm currently having a look at the IIS Web Farm Framework, but i'm concerned about performance.

Is there an important difference between a classic Load Balancer, and the WFF load balancing ?
Would it fit for a high trafic website (millions of views each month) ?
I searched the web for articles on WFF, but none seemed to make a benchmark or comparison with a classic load balancer.

And would there be Bandwith issues?

Thanks

Comment: This question is probably better served at [serverfault](http://serverfault.com). Top of my head, one aspect would be relying entirely on, and managing IIS boxes (yourself) vs purposely built appliances and/or (cloud) services/platforms (already tuned).

Comment: thank, i'll ask the question there

Comment: question asked here : http://serverfault.com/questions/669327/iis-web-farm-framework-load-balancing-vs-classic-load-balancing